# Use different tableview cells in edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I want to make something similar as in Contacts app:

There are some cells for standard mode
[image]
 and others for edit mode.
[image]
What I tried is:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if self.editing{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TextFieldCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as TextFieldTableViewCell
        return cell
    }else{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ButtonCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as ButtonTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Where and how should I trigger cells reloading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting the table view cells to reload to the appropriate edit/non-edit version of the cells anytime the user enters or leaves edit mode. If I understand that correctly, then you could provide a setter for the editing property to reload the table view cells anytime edit mode is change.

```
override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    self.tableView.endUpdates() 
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid reloading whole table.

Comment: It should only reload the cells that appear on screen. It doesn't reload every cell in the table view (if you have more cells than fit on screen at once).

EDIT: Here is a link to the documentation on reloadData(). See the second sentence in the discussion section.

Comment: @hunterbk89 I edited your answer to make it work. Currently what I don't understand is why `beginUpdates` doesn't do cell reloading as `reloadData` does. I will accept your answer if there will be no better answers.

Comment: `reloadData` should go before `beginUpdates` — then everything works well.